# link between two columns when generating random data

Tags: excel, random, matching

I have a spreadsheet of words in German and English.

For example:

```
          A          B           C          D
1     Hallo         Hello                  random word
2     Blau          Blue
3     Hund          Dog
4     Blumen        Flowers
5     Auto          Car
```

And in a random cell (say in cell D1) I can generate a random `german` word from column A using:

```
=INDEX($A:$A|RANDBETWEEN(1|COUNTA($A:$A))|1)
```

Now in E1, I want to print the appropriate `english` word. So when we press `F9` and generate a new random word, I always get the correction translation.

Any suggestions on how to make this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **E1**

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

where **D1** contains:

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In cell `E1` you can do this:

```
= INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(D1,$A:$A,0))
```

Although it is recommended to reduce the full-column arrays down to the end of your data. (e.g. if you have 100 rows of data, change to `$A$1:$A$100`)